# How can I blockpull an inactive domain?

Tags: libvirt, qemu, virsh

For active domain I can do `virsh blockpull --domain ... --path ... --base ...` I would expect the blockpull should also work with inactive domain since it should be even easier (there is no write operation from guest os interfering the merge operation.). However, I get `error: Requested operation is not valid: domain is not running`. Why? Is there any reason that blockpull cannot work with inactive domains?

What is the correct way to do a blockpull for inactive domain? Do I need to manually call qemu-img safe rebase on the immediate backing file of the current snapshot of that domain? It is kind of annoying that I have to manually find out which backing file path is.

Comment: Because it's based on Qemu `block-stream` operation. When Proxmox VE starts inherently Qemu-based operations on VMs that are not running, it starts a Qemu on them, though differently so it is very thin and the real VM's OS doesn't boot. Libvirt isn't as smart as that, so it simply forbids.